# Entity Framework .Where nested in .Include

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I'm attempting to perform a db lookup using EF5 code-first. The basic structure and table relationships are as follows;

```
public partial class Member
{
    public int    RecordID {get; set;}
    public string Name     {get; set;}
    ...etc.
    public virtual ICollection<MemberLink> MasterLinks {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<MemberLink> SlaveLinks {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Message>    ReceivedMessages {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Message>    SentMessages {get; set;}
}

public partial class MemberLink
{
    public int            RecordID     {get; set;}
    public virtual Member MasterMember {get; set;}
    public virtual Member SlaveMember  {get; set;}
    ...etc.
}

public partial class Message
{
    public int            RecordID  {get; set;}
    public virtual Member Sender    {get; set;}
    public virtual Member Recipient {get; set;}
    ...etc.
}
```

Now, the query I'm trying to perform is using the **MemberLinkRepository**, and looks like;

```
public IList<MemberLink> GetMasterLinks(int p_MemberID)
{
    return Get()
           .Include ( memberLink => memberLink.MasterMember )
           .Include ( memberLink => memberLink.SlaveMember )
           .Include ( memberLink => memberLink.MasterMember.ReceivedMessages
                      .Where(
                      msg => msg.Sender.RecordID == memberLink.SlaveMember.RecordID) )
           .Where ( memberLink => memberLink.MasterMember.RecordID == p_MemberID)
           .ToList();
```

Except EF doesn't seem to like the nested Where. I could split this out into 2 separate repository calls (and indeed, it's looking like I might have to do that) but in the interest of reducing calls to the db I'm trying to do it in one foul swoop. Does anyone know how I can achieve this in one single query?

I hope the code illustrates what I'm trying to do... If not, I'll try and explain a little better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is no, EF will not let you do that using `Include()`.

Think about the result if it let you do this: in one case your `MemberLink.MasterMember.ReceivedMessages` will be fully populated, on another identical looking object `MemberLink.MasterMember.ReceivedMessages` is actually a sub-set of messages! What happens if you try to add to the ReceivedMessages? What if the addition doesn't match the filter? It is a bag of hurt.

The answer is to use projections:

```
public IList<MemberLinkWithFiltereredMessages> GetMasterLinks(int p_MemberID)
{
    return Get()
        .Include(memberLink => memberLink.MasterMember)
        .Include(memberLink => memberLink.SlaveMember)
        .Where(memberLink => memberLink.MasterMember.RecordID == p_MemberID)
        .Select(memberLink => new MemberLinkWithFilteredMessages
        {
            MemberLink = memberLink,
            FilteredMessages = memberLink.MasterMember.ReceivedMessages
                .Where(msg => msg.Sender.RecordID == memberLink.SlaveMember.RecordID)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

What you are really doing is asking for a specific sub-set of information, so be explicit about it.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for. Agreed; your point about explicitly asking for a filtered sub-set is a better approach, so I'll follow that logic :)

Comment: @user1861826 if it answers your question, please remember to tick it :)

Comment: @TimothyWalters, I have the same issue.. In my case, the nesting goes deep down multiple layers, i managed to do a include you pointed out. In the SQL which got generated, i could see all columns are returning with different alias name as c1,c2 something like that. My question is , how i can form a nested DTO collection out of all my includes:(.. May be you can take the above example itself, in that we are returning all the columns without any custom DTO (which itself is collection of DTO's)