# LINQ Include on a one-to-many with .Where() not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to query Users including each user's Interests, but only where an Interest meets certain criteria:

```
  return db.Users.Include(u => u.Interests.Where(s => s.TenantId == tenantId))
```

But I get an error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.

I played with the idea of pushing the .Where outside, but haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Linq-to-entities does not support this feature.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework .Where nested in .Include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709386/entity-framework-where-nested-in-include)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include only some of the interests you won't be able to use the `Include` method, as it doesn't support this.  You'll need to manually join the `Interests` with the `Users`:

```
var query = from user in db.Users
    join interest in db.Interests.Where(s => s.TenantId == tenantId)
    on user.InterestId equals interest.Id //todo:  will need to be updated
    into interests;
    select new { user, interests};
```

Comment: Thanks Servy - I've never done a manual join before.  I tried this syntax but get an error on join - db.Users is an IQueryable, if it matters.

Comment: Well, the code has several points that will need to be altered to fit your specific code, and if there is an error, providing the error text is a good place to start.

Comment: The 'on user.InterestId' seems to be the first problem - I tried updating everything else.  'user' has many Interests, no UserId - Interest has a UserId though.

Comment: @RobVious There you go, update the line that I said would need to be updated based on your columns to include your actual columns.

Comment: I'm sorry - user doesn't have any columns related to Interest so I don't know how to change user.InterestId.  I've tried so many different things on that todo line

Comment: The two tables must have some information in common.  One has an identifier, and another has a foreign key that corresponds to that value.  Put in the primary and foreign key into that line.  If you don't have that, then how do you intend to determine if a given interest maps to that user or not?

Comment: the interest has a userId, but the user only has a navigation property... I'm trying 'on user.UserId equals interest.UserId' now

Comment: Updated my post to reflect my progress.  If you think I should make a new question for these syntax problems, I can do that.

Comment: @RobVious Well, two problems come to mind.  First, using the `Equals` method likely won't be able to be translated by the query provider, next casting `result.interests` to an `ICollection` is likely to fail; it's not a collection, consider using something like `ToList`.  Next, given those problems, I would expect no interests to be found; I see nothing wrong with the filtering of interests, so there should be no interests from other tenants possibly in the results; odds are there is something else going on.

Comment: @Servy can't you achive the same simply by doing `db.Users.Select(user => new {user,interests=user.Interests.Where(s => s.TenantId == tenantId)})` ? What is the join for?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
return db.Users.Include("Interests").Where(u => u.Interests.Any(i => i.TenantId == tenantId));
```

This causes the users to be loaded, but only where the tenantId matches. The Interests related entities will be eager loaded for those users when the query executes.

Comment: Thanks Steve - I tried this and get 'Cannot resolve expresion Where(lambda expression)... thoughts?

Comment: I made a slight change. I was going from memory. Give it a shot now.

Comment: This filters out the `users` that don't meet the given condition; the intention of the OP's code appears to be that the `Interests` shouldn't be loaded for such users, but that the rest of the data about the user *is* loaded.

Comment: @Servy - right - I'm trying to get a user with all Interests, and then filter those interests according to whether or not they are associated with a given tenant.