# Entity Framework using projection to eagerly load some items with null check

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have received an `EntityCommandCompilationException` with an inner exception of "The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'" for the following very simply Entity Framework query:

```
    var myQuery = from bp in dbContext.MyBackpacks
                  select new
                  {
                      myContainer = bp.ContainerInBackpack,
                      myContainerContents = (bp.ContainerInBackpack == null) ? null : bp.ContainerInBackpack.Contents.Where(x => x.ContentsString == "Beverage"),
                  };
    var myList = myQuery.ToList();
```

My entities and the relevant portion of the data context are defined as follows:

```
    public class MyBackpack
    {
        public Guid MyBackpackID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContainerInBackpackID")]
        public virtual MyContainer ContainerInBackpack { get; set; }
        public Guid? ContainerInBackpackID { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContainer
    {
        public Guid MyContainerID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MyContainerContents> Contents { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContainerContents
    {
        public Guid MyContainerContentsID { get; set; }
        public string ContentsString { get; set; }
        public Guid? MyContainerID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MyContainerID")]
        public virtual MyContainer MyContainer { get; set; }
    }

    // ...

    public virtual DbSet<MyContainerContents> MyContents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MyContainer> MyContainers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MyBackpack> MyBackpacks { get; set; }
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.1. The problem exists with both settings of `UseNullDatabaseSemantics`. I understand from other posts that the designers of Entity Framework decided not to support this scenario, but would like to know if anyone has a suggested workaround that would return all the data in a single trip to the database. I realize that one workaround would be to simply use `Include` to return all items of type `MyContainerContents` but I would like the projection to return only the matching container contents. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709729/3849823) seems to suggest that using projections is a recommended way of returning some related items, but as this example indicates, I have not been able to get this approach to work consistently. (Indeed, with some other examples, I have encountered a StackOverflowException in the Entity Framework code, but we'll leave that for another occasion.)

UPDATE: In response to @usr's suggestion, I took out the null reference check. That produced a single query and no error. So, it is sometimes possible to early load some members of a subcollection using a projection. But it would be helpful if there were some guidance about when doing this and when using subqueries and null reference checks will make things too complicated for Entity Framework. Here's the SQL without the null reference check (of course, as noted above, no SQL was generated with the null reference check):

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[MyBackpackID] AS [MyBackpackID], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID] AS [ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project2].[MyContainerContentsID] AS [MyContainerContentsID], 
    [Project2].[ContentsString] AS [ContentsString], 
    [Project2].[MyContainer_MyContainerID] AS [MyContainer_MyContainerID]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project1].[MyBackpackID] AS [MyBackpackID], 
        [Project1].[ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID] AS [ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project1].[MyContainerContentsID] AS [MyContainerContentsID], 
        [Project1].[ContentsString] AS [ContentsString], 
        [Project1].[MyContainer_MyContainerID] AS [MyContainer_MyContainerID], 
        CASE WHEN ([Project1].[MyContainerContentsID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[MyBackpackID] AS [MyBackpackID], 
            [Extent1].[ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID] AS [ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID], 
            1 AS [C1], 
            [Extent2].[MyContainerContentsID] AS [MyContainerContentsID], 
            [Extent2].[ContentsString] AS [ContentsString], 
            [Extent2].[MyContainer_MyContainerID] AS [MyContainer_MyContainerID]
            FROM  [dbo].[MyBackpacks] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MyContainerContents] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[MyContainer_MyContainerID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID] = [Extent2].[MyContainer_MyContainerID]) AND (N'Beverage' = [Extent2].[ContentsString])
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[MyBackpackID] ASC, [Project2].[ContainerInBackpack_MyContainerID] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This projection will not give you any efficiency gains anyway because you cannot eagerly load sub-collections in the same query. All this does is issue one subquery per outer item. The select n+1 problem.

The linked answer has this problem.

The answer is therefore: What you want is possible but not efficiently. Here's an inefficient workaround:

```
myContainerContents = bp.ContainerInBackpack.Contents
   .Where(x => bp.ContainerInBackpack != null && x.ContentsString == "Beverage"),
```

This returns an empty sequence in case the condition is false.

Comment: Julie Lerman offers an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx) (see section "Query Projections as an Alternative to Loading") in which portions of a subcollection are loaded via a projection "in a single trip to the database." Why is this example different? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm very skeptical of that claim. Try using SQL Profiler to see what gets executed and post all queries in the question. Probably, multiple SQL queries are executed if you execute the LINQ query and access the subcollections (to force evaluation).

Comment: Lerman appears to be correct. (See update above.) The inefficient workaround of @usr would work if we first loaded all backpacks and checked for whether ContainerInBackpack is non null (you put the null check in the wrong place). But I have added a clarification that I would like to know if there is a way to process the query in a single round trip to the database. The answer may be "no" with the null reference check, though it would be helpful to understand just when you can and can't use a projection to eagerly load some items in the collection.

Comment: I put the null check in the right place. EF can't deal with the null check outside of the subquery. So I put it inside. This results in an empty sequence in case the check turns out false. Interestingly, EF supports eager loading that way. This should work. Do you disagree?

Comment: The bp.ContainerInBackpack.Contents will produce a NullReferenceException, before we even get to the Where query, if bp.ContainerInBackpack == null. (I tried this just to make sure.)