# Filter a property IENumerable to only include items that pass a test

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have a list of items, Articles, and each article can have a series of reviews. Right now I grab the list of articles from my database using Entity Framework in my controller, db.Articles and I send that to my view. In my view I want to display all the articles and some of the reviews. For instance, the reviews done by a certain user.

The way I do this know looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { //item is a article, model is IEnumerable<Article>
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
      <td>

        @foreach (var reviewStatus in item.ReviewStatus.Where(u=> u.user.Id == ViewBag.userId))
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => reviewStatus.Status)
            @Html.Raw(", ")
        }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

I feel like there should be a way in my Controller to send Articles that already have this filter applied so that I don't have to do it in my view (since it can be a bit slow).

Comment: yes you should get filtered records in view

Comment: chech out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709386/entity-framework-where-nested-in-include it's pritty much what you want to do

Comment: Batavia, thanks I think I can get away with it with projections, though having to create a new object for every item seems annoying and not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily it is not good that you are using the Entity Framework object as model for your view. Model in MVC is conceptually still element in UI layer, but EF is far away from it in persistence layer. And you should have at least domain and business logic layer in between.

What I usually do is to define the Model as an extra class, I construct the instance of class in controller action handler and I take all the data I need within the view from that instance (which is available in view as Model indeed).

In your case the class(es) would look somehow like this:

```
public class ArticleModel {
  public string Title { get; set; } 
  // other article properties

  private IEnumerable<ReviewModel> reviews;
  public IEnumerable<ReviewModel> Reviews {
    get {
      if (reviews == null) {
        // lazy loader to get ReviewModels from your business/domain logic
      }
      return reviews;
    }
  }
}

public class ArticlesPageModel {
  public string PageTitle { get; set; }

  private IEnumerable<ArticleModel> articles;
  public IEnumerable<ArticleModel> Articles {
    get {
      if (articles == null) {
        // lazy load articles from business/domain logic
      }
      return articles;
    }
  }
}
```

etc... I hope you see the pattern...

Usually my "model" classes have a constructor, which takes domain object (EF entity in your case) and they know how to initialize themselves.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a separate UI model and data model.

Comment: Yea, I do see how a data model and a UI model can / should be implemented. Sadly the project I'm working on is really only "meant" to be a short term solution until an outside firm completely rebuilds it, so its a debate about doing things "right" / doing things easy / fast.

Comment: I wrote the code above in 10 minutes. It is usual misconception that right and easy are in conflict. And there is another misconception, that the software you are writing will be replaced soon.
Anyway, if the project is not important, it is ideal place to learn and experiment with the proper structure of the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the action in your controller you can do something like this:

```
    var allArticles = new IEnumerable<Article>();
    allArticles = db.GetAllArticles(); //or whatever method that you have for grabing everything from db

   var filteredArticles = allArticles.FinAll(x=>x.ReviewStatus != null && x.ReviewStatus.Count > 0 && x.ReviewStatus.Exists(u=> u.user.Id == 1234) && x.ReviewStatus.Exists(u.otherCriteria = 4321 ));
   foreach(var article in filterArticles)
{
    var specificReviews_1 = article.ReviewStatus.FinaAll(u=> u.user.Id == 1234).Take(3);
    var specificReviews_2 = article.ReviewStatus.FinaAll(u=> u.user.Id != 1234 && u.otherCriteria = 4321).Take(3);
    article.ReviewStatus = new List<ReviewStatus>();
    article.ReviewStatus.AddRange(specificReviews_1 );
    article.ReviewStatus.AddRange(specificReviews_2 );

}   
return View("yourView", filterArticles);
```

and then in view do something like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
      <td>

        @foreach (var reviewStatus in item.ReviewStatus)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => reviewStatus.Status)
            @Html.Raw(", ")
        }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: This wont work since every article has multiple reviews. I want article.Reviews to have a specific kind of review only in my view.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't saw the ViewBag part! what is the criteria for getting that specific kind of reviews? I get that part that you said some special user should has a review but what else?

Comment: I will edit the source code, but first please give me more info.

Comment: using this method you can grab at the most 6 reviews that are satisfying your criteria.