# How to perform a conditional include in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently using EF and I have two tables, `Employees` and `Orders`, given that an `Employee` have multiple `Orders`.

I need to perform a query in EF that brings me a list of all `Employees` with their related `Orders`, but only those between two dates. If an `Employee` didn't perform any `Order` in the given period, his `Orders` list will be empty.

I figured that I need to start my query from the `Employees` DbSet, but how can I assign a condition to the `Orders` property?

I tried to do this, but obviously it didn't work.

```
public List<Employee> GetAllByIdListAndDateRange(int[] ids, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        var query = _context.Set<Employee>().Where(a => ids.Contains(a.EmployeeID)).Include(a => a.Orders.Where(o.OrderDate <= toDate && o.OrderDate >= fromDate));

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Any help? I guess I might be missing out on something really simple here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework .Where nested in .Include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709386/entity-framework-where-nested-in-include)

Comment: use left outer join.refer to this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Answer (score 2):

You cant use a Where predicate in Include, but you can simplify your query if you start from Orders.

If you think it again what you need to query is orders not Employees.

```
var query = _context.Set<Orders>()
                    .Where(o => o.OrderDate <= toDate &&
                                o.OrderDate >= fromDate && 
                                ids.Contains(o.EmployeeID))
                    .Include(e => e.Employee));
```

Comment: This would almost solve my problem, but I intend to iterate through the `Employee` DbSet. Using your answer, I wouldn't be able to retrieve an Employee that had no Orders. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try to replace

```
myQuery.Include(x=>x.Y).Load();
```

by :

```
myQuery.Load();
myQuery.SelectMany(x=>x.y).Where( ....).Load();
```